# Switching from 3 columns to 2

Tags: css, width

I have a responsive layout set up for 3 columns. In each column is a product that we are trying to sell. Sometimes there could be 3 items, 2 items and 1 item. Currently when I remove 1 item it will display on 2/3 of the page and leave the 1/3 empty. How do I create it so that when there are 2 or 1 item being displayed for them to be centered and they would have a max-width of 640px?

```
/* -------- HTML ------------*/ 

<div class="item">Item1</div>
<div class="item">Item1</div>
<div class="item">Item1</div>

/* -------- CSS ------------*/ 

.item {
display: inline;
float: left;
width: 33.33%;
}
```

Comment: Flexbox might work better for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With flexbox, the container will fill 100% of the space based on how many `item`s you have.

HTML

```
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="item">Item1</div>
  <div class="item">Item2</div>
  <div class="item">Item3</div>
</div>

<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="item">Item1</div>
  <div class="item">Item2</div>
</div>

<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="item">Item1</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.item {
  flex: 1;
}
```

[Here is an example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMBQVb)

Comment: Whenever it shows 2 items, there is a space between each side like there is a padding issue. There isn't a padding being declared. Could it be the flex:1 causing this?

Answer (score 0):

A flex box would better suit your need. Remove/add item to see how the columns adapt to your new content:

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
}
.item{
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Item1</div>
  <div class="item">Item2</div>
  <div class="item">Item3</div>
</div>
```